# How to create non-stacked subbars chart using core-plot?

Tags: ios, core-plot, diagrams

I need to display bar-chart diagram.
The main issue I've not found yet is how to display bars with sub-bars.
So the first bar consists of green bar (with 5  points for y) at bottom and yellow bar (with 3 points for y). 
And the second bar consists of pink bar at bottom (with 3 points for y)
So my bars **are not stacked.** - I can have even no bars for next x, but I can have 3 sub-bars in one bar  in different order.

Generally the following image shows what bars do I need.
[Generally the following image shows what bars do I need.](http://postimg.org/image/yfuudylyz/)

Comment: Please explain your question properly. Consider adding links to images which show the expected output and the desired output. Also add some relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different bar plot for each fill pattern. Set `barBasesVary` to `YES` on each plot so you can control the ends of bars individually. The plot will query the datasource for three values for each bar: the location (the horizontal position for vertical bars), the tip (the top) value, and the base (the bottom) value. The "Vertical Bar Chart" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app shows a simple example of this technique.